# DropDownList returning a object, not only a ID value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want a solution to implement a property (or method) to return the selected object.

Example:

```
DropDownListUser.DataSource = UserList;
User user = (User)DropDownListUser.SelectedObject;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The web is stateless, despite ASP .NET magic. All you need is the selected `Value` property. During post back you should be able to find the object based on the value. This is how it's intended to work anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The `DropDownList` doesn't actually store the entire object during the binding, only the Text and Value as defined by `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`. In order to get a selected object back, you are going to have to store the *entire* list of objects locally in the page (such as in `ViewState`). You'll also have to come up with your own `DropDownList` implementation to handle marshalling the list to and from local storage.

I think it would be simpler to cache the list locally (to save yourself a trip back to the database) and just do the lookup using the `SelectedValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Patrick, looking at this history, looks like you can't do that without creating a custom dropdownlist

- [Problem with getting selected OBJECT from dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646625/problem-with-getting-selected-object-from-dropdownlist)
- [DropDownList get underlying object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032853/dropdownlist-get-underlying-object)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Web `dropdownlist` is `not like` the window forms `combo` to bind it with class. It has collection of `ListItems` which has `Value` and `Text`. So you can only get Text or Value from it. More about [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dzka5sf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the DropDownList and make it keep the list of objects in the session.

Like this:

DropDownListKeepRef:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Q11456633WebApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension of <see cref="DropDownList"/> supporting reference to the 
    /// object related to the selected line.
    /// </summary>
    [ValidationProperty("SelectedItem")]
    [SupportsEventValidation]
    [ToolboxData(
      "<{0}:DropDownListKeepRef runat=\"server\"></{0}:DropDownListKeepRef>")]
    public class DropDownListKeepRef : DropDownList
    {
        protected override void PerformDataBinding(System.Collections.IEnumerable dataSource)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DataValueField))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "'DataValueField' cant be define in this implementation. This Control use the index of list");
            }

            this.Items.Clear();
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            int valueInt = 0;
            if (this.FirstNull)
            {
                list.Add(null);
                this.Items.Add(new ListItem(this.FirstNullText, valueInt.ToString()));
                valueInt++;
            }
            foreach (object item in dataSource)
            {
                String textStr = null;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    Object textObj = item.GetType().GetProperty(this.DataTextField).GetValue(item, null);
                    textStr = textObj != null ? textObj.ToString() : "";
                }
                else
                {
                    textStr = "";
                }

                //montando a listagem
                list.Add(item);
                this.Items.Add(new ListItem(textStr, valueInt.ToString()));
                valueInt++;
            }
            this.listOnSession = list;
        }

        private bool firstNull = false;
        /// <summary>
        /// If <c>true</ c> include a first line that will make reference to <c>null</c>,
        /// otherwise there will be only the line from the DataSource.
        /// </summary>
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        [Themeable(false)]
        public bool FirstNull
        {
            get
            {
                return firstNull;
            }
            set
            {
                firstNull = value;
            }
        }

        private string firstNullText = "";
        /// <summary>
        /// Text used if you want a first-line reference to <c>null</c>.
        /// </summary>
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Themeable(false)]
        public virtual string FirstNullText
        {
            get
            {
                return firstNullText;
            }
            set
            {
                firstNullText = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// List that keeps the object instances.
        /// </summary>
        private IList listOnSession
        {
            get
            {
                return this.listOfListsOnSession[this.UniqueID + "_listOnSession"];
            }
            set
            {
                this.listOfListsOnSession[this.UniqueID + "_listOnSession"] = value;
            }
        }

        #region to avoid memory overload
        private string currentPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["DdlkrCurrentPage"];
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["DdlkrCurrentPage"] = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Every time you change page, lists for the previous page will be 
        /// discarded from memory.
        /// </summary>
        private IDictionary<String, IList> listOfListsOnSession
        {
            get
            {
                if (currentPage != this.Page.Request.ApplicationPath)
                {
                    currentPage = this.Page.Request.ApplicationPath;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["DdlkrListOfListsOnSession"] = new Dictionary<String, IList>();
                }
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["DdlkrListOfListsOnSession"] == null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["DdlkrListOfListsOnSession"] = new Dictionary<String, IList>();
                }

                return (IDictionary<String, IList>)HttpContext.Current.Session["DdlkrListOfListsOnSession"];
            }
        } 
        #endregion

        public Object SelectedObject
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.SelectedIndex > 0 && this.listOnSession.Count > this.SelectedIndex)
                    return this.listOnSession[this.SelectedIndex];
                else
                    return null;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!this.listOnSession.Contains(value))
                {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(
                        "Objeto nao contido neste 'DropDownListKeepRef': " +
                        value != null ? value.ToString() : "<null>");
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SelectedIndex = this.listOnSession.IndexOf(value);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// List of related objects.
        /// </summary>
        public IList Objects
        {
            get
            {
                return new ArrayList(this.listOnSession);
            }
        }

        [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
        {
            object[] totalState = null;
            if (savedState != null)
            {
                totalState = (object[])savedState;
                if (totalState.Length != 3)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("View State Invalida!");
                }
                // Load base state.
                int i = 0;
                base.LoadViewState(totalState[i++]);
                // Load extra information specific to this control.
                this.firstNull = (bool)totalState[i++];
                this.firstNullText = (String)totalState[i++];
            }
        }

        [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        protected override object SaveViewState()
        {
            object baseState = base.SaveViewState();
            object[] totalState = new object[3];
            int i = 0;
            totalState[i++] = baseState;
            totalState[i++] = this.firstNull;
            totalState[i++] = this.firstNullText;
            return totalState;
        }
    }
}
```

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Q11456633WebApp._Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Q11456633WebApp" Namespace="Q11456633WebApp" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <cc1:DropDownListKeepRef ID="ListofDatesDdlkr" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="Date" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListofDatesDdlkr_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </cc1:DropDownListKeepRef>&nbsp;</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace Q11456633WebApp
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.ListofDatesDdlkr.DataSource = this.ListOfDate;
                this.ListofDatesDdlkr.DataBind();
            }
        }

        private DateTime[] ListOfDate
        {
            get
            {
                return new DateTime[]
                {
                    new DateTime(2012, 7, 1),
                    new DateTime(2012, 7, 2),
                    new DateTime(2012, 7, 3),
                    new DateTime(2012, 7, 4),
                    new DateTime(2012, 7, 5),
                };
            }
        }

        protected void ListofDatesDdlkr_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                this.GetType(), 
                "show_type", 
                String.Format(
                    "alert('Type of SelectedObject:{0}')", 
                    this
                        .ListofDatesDdlkr
                            .SelectedObject
                                .GetType()
                                    .FullName), 
                    true);
        }
    }
}
```

Solution with the complete sample code: [Q11456633WebApp.7z](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/Q11456633WebApp.7z)

Comment: Using `ViewState` and `Session` with reckless abandon is why so many ASP .NET applications perform poorly and / or have outrageous memory requirements...

Comment: I agree. This requires some approach to clean up the data. Maybe something like: when entering a page, clearing the lists of other pages.